# resizing columns after a reload

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jqgrid

im using jqgrid, and for some reason, after i use `'reloadGrid'` one column change its width.

```
conf_users = BindJQGrid("#usersList", {
    url : humanportal.sysvar.humandns + 'groups.json',
    rowheight : 30,
    colNames : [
                    '#',
                    '<?php echo $this->lang->trans('group', 'attrs')?>',
                    ''
                ],
    colModel : [
                    {sortable:false, align:'center', title:false, width:50},
                    {sortable:false, name:'name', index:'name', width:300},
                    {sortable:false, align:'right', title:false, width:200}
                ],
    rowNum : 50,
```

Where i call the reload:

```
conf_users.sortableRows({
    update: function(event,ui) {
        var rows = $("#usersList").getDataIDs();
        for (i=1 ; i<=rows.length; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                url: humanportal.sysvar.humandns + 'groups/setattribute/' + rows[i-1] + '.personal?json=1&attr=level&val=' + i ,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function() {
                    conf_users.trigger('reloadGrid');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

any help would be appreciated,
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you always want the columns to have the width you have specified add fixed: true to each column.

Example:

```
{sortable:false, align:'right', title:false, width:200, fixed: true}
```

Comment: that didn't work, but i noticed this problem is only happening on Chrome.. when i figured out why ill post